# How these lines execute

Tags: c++

Guys i'm having a problem to understand these three lines of code. What i'm doing is taking three `string` objects of same constructor arguments. But facing a problem to understand how code works in these three lines. I Know
`begin()` function either return an iterator or const_iterator that refers to the first element of a container.
`end()` function either return an iterator or const_iterator that refers to the next position after the end of the container.
`erase()` function removes one or more elements from the container.
But what does `remove()` function does?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;




int main() {

    string str = "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\">";
    string str2 = "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\">";
    string str3 = "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\">";


    remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\"');

    str2.erase(remove(str2.begin(), str2.end(), '\"'));

    str3.erase(remove(str3.begin(), str3.end(), '\"'),str3.end());


    cout << str << endl;

    cout << str2 << endl;

    cout << str3 << endl;


}
```

Output:

```
<tag1 value = HelloWorld>">
<tag1 value = HelloWorld>>
<tag1 value = HelloWorld>
```

Comment: Hint: you're getting `remove` wrong. It doesn't actually remove anything.

Comment: Do a websearch for the Erase-Remove Idiom. [Docs on `std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)